# Canvas Drawing lines are very slow in phonegap with android

Tags: iphone, android, cordova

I am using phogegap to develop my drawing app. When user touch with the finger and move around, multiple lines can be drawn. But this app is very slow/slugging in android emulator and android device.

The same coding work fine for iPhone Simulator.

Note: In android emulator I can see the following messages.
[[Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.]]

Any suggestion.

Comment: That's why it's recommended to use default development tools?

Comment: The appreciate default tool suggestion,now how can I resolve this issue if already has used phonegap framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging the android handset after installing the app on it. I have found that my apps are generally much slower (even on a handset) when they have an active debugging session connected to the device. In other words, just run the app without a debugger attached and see if its any faster.

Phone gap is never going to be as fast as a fully native application. If you are going graphics intensive stuff then prepare to be disappointed...